# Recibir Datos de PHP con AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

La idea es que al presionar el boton actualizar en PHP se ejecute la sentencia en MYSQL y esos datos regresarlos a JS y por medio de un success solo mostrar los titulos de una columna.

```
//JS
    'use stric'
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#actualizar").on('click',function(){
            var id="";
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'php/Spend.php',
                data:{'id':id},
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(typeof data);
                    $("#request").text(data.titulo_solicitud);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Hasta aqui en la consola me muestra todo el codigo de php (data) y es de tipo string el data.

En PHP no tengo problemas con la conexion a la BD incluso al ejecutar un print_r o var_dump a la variable $json_array muestra todos los datos. el problema esta en el json_enconde que no muestra nada y por lo mismo no puedo acceder a ellos desde el success de Js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MySQLToJson</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

    try{
        require_once('conexion_BD.php');
        $sql="SELECT `titulo_solicitud` FROM solicitudes"; //Aqui va la consulta
        $resultado=$conn->query($sql); //recoge los valores de la consulta
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }

        $json_array= array();

 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {      
        $json_array[]=$row;

 }

echo json_encode($json_array);

    $conn->close();?>
</body>
</html>
```

En este punto necesitaria que los datos del array lo convierta en objeto para poder acceder a ellos en el success de ajax e imprimirlos en un div.

sí comento el json_encode y solo dejo el var_dump o print_r ($json_array) el success de JS me mustra en el div todo el array y solo necesito lo que hay en [titulo_solicitud]. Esto es lo que recibo en el Div si coloco en php var_dump o print_r.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>MySQLToJson</title> </head> <body> <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>conexion</title> </head> <body> </body> </html>Array ( [0] => Array ( [titulo_solicitud] => No puedo acceder a IDSE ) [1] => Array ( [titulo_solicitud] => Atenci�n a t�cnico de telmex ) [2] => Array ( [titulo_solicitud] => No puedo acceder a la BD Access ) [3] => Array ( [titulo_solicitud] => No puedo acceder a la BD Access ) [4] => Array ( [titulo_solicitud] => No hay conexi�n a la BD desde la bodega. ) [5] => Array ( [titulo_solicitud] => ) [6] => Array ( [titulo_solicitud] => Tu cola ) [7] => Array ( [titulo_solicitud] => Tu cola ) [8] => Array ( [titulo_solicitud] => Sin acceso a BD ) ) </body> </html>
```

No hay errores en la consola de desarrollador, solo se queda en blanco al usar echo json_encode($json_array);

Comment: por que recorres el resultado ` while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))` y lo entregas a un array y no simplemente devuelves el array `mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)`?

Comment: Por que solo me muesta el primer titulo de la solicitud y requiero todos, para poder tenerlos a la vista.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir lo que sale en `console.log(data);` para ver cómo están estructurados los datos que devuelve el servidor?

Comment: Si utilizo un print_r o un var_dump me muestra los datos de la columna en un array pero si utilizo el json_encode no muestra ningun dato

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero algunas cosas:

1. Que pongas el `dataType` a la solicitud de Ajax
2. Que en coherencia con esto, pongas un `header` en el servidor
3. Es mejor que el bloque `while` esté dentro del bloque `try`...
4. Para mostrar todos los datos, tienes que recorrer el JSON en el `success`. Aquí los guardamos en `txtOutput` y actualizamos el contenedor una sola vez.
5. Una cosa muy importante, para tus peticiones Ajax tu archivo **`php/Spend.php`** no debería tener etiquetas HTML ni nada que salga por pantalla, **solamente los datos que Ajax necesite**. Los archivos que se usan para pedir los datos son archivos auxiliares, no están destinados a mostrar nada por pantalla al cliente desde el archivo mismo. **Nótese** que en caso de error pondremos una clave `error` en el array y en el `success` es lo primero que vamos a verificar.

El código sería entonces así:

#### JS

```
'use stric'
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#actualizar").on('click',function(){
        var id="";
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'php/Spend.php',
            data:{'id':id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                var txtOutput="";
                if (data.error){
                    txtOutput=data.error;
                } else {
                    $.each(data, function(i, value) {
                        txtOutput += value.titulo_solicitud;
                    });
                }
                $("#request").text(txtOutput);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

#### PHP

```
<?php 
    $json_array= array();
    
    try{
        require_once('conexion_BD.php');
        $sql="SELECT `titulo_solicitud` FROM solicitudes"; //Aqui va la consulta
        $resultado=$conn->query($sql); //recoge los valores de la consulta
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {      
            $json_array[]=$row;
        }
        $conn->close();
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        $json_array ['error']=$e->getMessage();
    }   
    
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($json_array);
?>
```

Comment: Lo intente como me indicaste pero obtuve este error en el response del navegador "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: @ivaN en el archivo `Spend.php` no puedes tener cosas como estas: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MySQLToJson</title>
</head>
<body>` porque todo eso se meterá en la respuesta y no estarás recibiendo un JSON válido. Debe ser un archivo PHP limpio, sin contenido HTML ninguno ni ningún `echo, print`, etc, fuera del JSON. ¿Corregiste eso?

Comment: Hola!! Ya lo resolví, el problema esta en la BD tenía acentos en algunos registros, aunque esta configurado con UTF-8 que tengo entendido que acepta acentos, genera algunos errores en el json_encode(); 

Amigo muchas gracias por tu tiempo y apoyo el ejemplo que me pusiste si me funciono al final.

Comment: @ivaN con la base de datos conviene indicar al objeto de conexión que quieres que trabaje con `utf-8`. Esto se hace de varios modos, según uses PDO o mysqli. Con eso y los header no deberías tener problemas de codificación, [revisa esta respuesta (sobre todo lo que se dice del **nivel 3**)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967) cuando te sea posible. Saludos.

Comment: Lo mismo pense estos 3 días que me encontré con este problema pero en fin, por el momento adelantare lo atrasado e iré buscando más información con los acentos ya que seguro los necesitare más adelante.

Comment: @ivaN Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.