# Actualizar div con PHP mysql sin recargar pagina

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

estoy aprendiendo ajax, tengo una duda;

Tengo un formulario con 4 campos [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="fecha_ini">Fecha de inicio</label>
    <input id="fecha_ini" class="form-control" type="date" min="2016-01-01" value="2020-01-01" onChange="updateMin()"/>
    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2 pb-0 mb-0" role="alert" id="minDateError" style="display: none">
<span><p>Favor de introducir una fecha.</p></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<label for="fecha_fin">Fecha final</label>
<input id="fecha_fin" class="form-control" type="date" min="2016-01-01" onChange="updateMax()"/>
<div class="alert alert-danger mt-2 pb-0 mb-0" role="alert" id="maxDateError" style="display: none">
<span><p>Favor de introducir una fecha.</p></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<label for="mercado">Mercado</label>
<select id="mercado" class="form-control selectpicker">
<option value="MDA">MDA</option>
<option value="MTR">MTR</option>                            
</select>
</div
```

> 

Necesito con forme a lo que se seleccione haga una consulta a una base e imprima ese resultado en un div sin recargar la pagina completa.

Algun lugar donde pueda ver un ejemplo en el cual pueda basarme?

Gracias.

Comment: [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248983/recibir-datos-de-php-con-ajax) tal vez te ayude

Comment: Puedes usar JQuery, la función .load() [más información](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda lo implemente con ajax y la funcin .load() para cargar un div con la respuesta a la actualizacion gracias.